# tikz `postaction` using `edge`

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, edge

### Problem

I want to add a tikz `style` which affects only some arrows in a large diagram, and adds a `postaction`. I also need to bend and label these arrows, so many are created using the `edge` command.

However, as noted in [this Tikz manual](https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf) (pp 131, section 13.11), `edge` paths are computed after the main path. As a result (I think), `postaction` fails on `edge` arrows.

### Question

Can I use `postaction` on `edge` paths? If so, how?

### Example

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  arrow/.style = { -stealth, red, line width = 2mm,
    postaction = { draw, blue, line width = 1mm, shorten >=1mm }
  }
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[arrow] (0,0)  --  (+1,+1);
    \draw[arrow] (0,0) edge (-1,-1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Produces

[image]

#### Desired

[image]

Comment: you can but you have to add to the `edge` options not the `draw`

Comment: This gives the error: `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/edge' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \draw[arrow] (0,0) -- (+1,+);`

Comment: Just restating what @percusse said: try `\draw (0,0) edge[arrow] (-1,-1);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to apply the arrow style to the edges not to the whole path. For this you can use `every edge` style. And as said @percusse in his comment you have to add `draw` in the style.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  arrow/.style = {-stealth, draw=red, line width = 2mm,
    postaction = { draw=blue, line width = 1mm, shorten >=1mm }
  },
  earrow/.style={
    every edge/.style={arrow}
  }
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[arrow] (0,0)  --  (+1,+1);
    \draw[earrow] (0,0) edge (-1,-1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct way to get what you want is defining the start and end using `<arrow_tip>-<arrow_tip>`, normally is `<->`, but for your style should be `stealth-stealth`.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  arrow/.style = {
    draw,
    red,
    stealth-stealth,
    line width = 2mm,
    postaction = {
        draw,
        blue,
        line width = 1mm,
        shorten >=1mm,
        shorten <=1mm,
        stealth-stealth
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[arrow] (-1,-1)  --  (1,1);
    \draw[arrow] (1,-1)  -|  (3,1);
    \draw[arrow] (4,-1)  .. controls +(right:2cm) and +(down:2cm) .. (6,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I don't want to draw two-headed arrows. I was just using this example to contrast the results of `--` and `edge`